# Sending Mail in custom subfolder of inbox using java mail

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-mail

I am working a java-ee project which has a feature of sending and reading mail.
So, I want to send mail which goes to a custom **subfolder**(that I'll be able to create if not exist) inside inbox, so that I can search for that mail in that **subfolder** by giving certain header value.

I am using outlook.office.com as host imap protocol.

Is there any way to do this?
I would appreciate any help.
regards

Comment: Which mail API are you using?

Comment: i m using javax-mail api

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292488/creating-folders-in-imap-does-not-work

Comment: in the above link, thta code is to create a folder, but how to check  if that folder already exists.

Comment: and how can i send mail to that folder?

Comment: If you check the code carefully, there is a flag maintained that'll help you with "exists-or-not" status.

Comment: that flag is not helpful at all, if you need to check that whether folder exists or not, you need to try opening that folder, it'll throw FolderNotFoundException if folder doesnot exists.

Comment: But my question was to how to send an email to a folder other than inbox or a SUB-FOLDER inside inbox. I know mail goes to inbox folder by default, but is there any way to sent that mail to a SUB-FOLDER of inbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't "send" mail to a folder, you "save" it in a folder.  Use the [Folder.appendMessages](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#appendMessages-javax.mail.Message:A-) method to append the message to a [Folder](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Folder.html).

Comment: Are you sure this is an answer? OP probably means to say what you're saying. He's clearly talking about mail filters.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't clear whether he wanted to use JavaMail to put the message in the folder, or whether he wanted the message to magically appear in the folder and then use JavaMail to read it.  If the latter, he needs to use a server-side filter, which outlook.office.com probably supports, or he can write a JavaMail program to search the messages in the Inbox and move them to another folder based on whatever criteria he wants.